# explanation about $ \iint_B \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}dB$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I require explanation about the following integral.

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$ and B is a triangle and his vertex are $(0,0)$ $(2,0)$ $(2,1)$

I would like an explanation why$$ \iint_B \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}dB$$

is not integratable.

The function is not continuous at $(0,0)$, is that enough for it to not be integratable?

Also, I was told the function's repeated integrals exists, I know it comes from Fubini's theorem but I don't understand what they are and how to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$. Then
$$\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}\,dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\frac{r^4\sin 2\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}{r^6}r\,dr d\theta=\frac{f(\theta)}{r}\,dr d\theta$$
For some continuous function of $\theta$. Since the triangle intersects every nbd of $r=0$, you see that the function is not integrable, because $1/r$ is not integrable in a nbd of zero.

Comment: nice solution, I will delete mine :-)

Comment: that is a very clear solution. thank you. do you have some insight about the second question?

Comment: Yes I do. Describe the triangle as $\{(x,y): 0\leq x\leq 1, x\leq y\leq x/2\}$. Calculate the integral with respect to $y$, and deduce that you cannot integrate the resulting function of $x$ from $0$ to $2$. Alternatively, describe the triangle as $\{(x,y): 0\leq y \leq 1, 2y\leq x\leq 2\}$, and calculate the integral with respect to $x$. Deduce that you cannot integrate the resulting function of $y$ from $0$ to $1$. So some of the iterated integrals exist, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be the smallest angle of your triangle. Then yor integral $I$ is such that $$I>\lim_{a\to0}\int_{r=a}^{1}\int_{\theta=0}^{\alpha}\frac{\sin \theta \cos \theta\left(\cos^2 \theta-\sin^2\theta\right)}{r}drd\theta=-\frac18\sin^2(2\alpha)\lim_{a\to0}\ln(a)$$

Comment: don't delete that :) I need any "ammo" I can use for the test. thank you

Comment: the solution is identical to the other ... but I will keep it :-) btw: what is "ammo"?

Comment: ammunition, bullets you use in guns, it's an allegory because passing that test will be a tough fight

Comment: well, then good luck!